# Trying to get the Widget Layer Rule Provider in Orchard to work with a wildcard

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I am working with Orchard CMS v0.8 and am trying to set the layer rule for a particular layer in a website. This can be done by looking at the "Orchard_Widgets_LayerPartRecord" table in the database.

There is a field whereby you can specify what they layer rule is which is great. However I am having a little trouble with getting it to match on a wildcard.

For example: I would want a layer rule to be url "~/admin/*" so that all pages that matched this url would have the layer.

I checked the underlying code and it appears that it should match however it does not. Anyone have any ideas?

I have had a look at this blog article which is great but it doesn't help in this situation. [Bertrand Le Roy's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/10/28/a-quick-look-at-what-s-new-in-orchard-0-8.aspx).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the developers replied with: This bug has been fixed in the developer branch and will be available in the next release.

http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/16711